# Creating a generic service comprising another service

Tags: api-design, middleware

Currently I have an existing API for my AI Engine, and a python wrapper to interact with the API. So this wrapper acts like a helper class to help format and automate some of the process that is needed to call the API.

There are 2 ways to interact with the API

1. User (using Jupyter Notebook - python) => Python Wrapper => API
2. Another program (any programming language) => API

Now, I have another AI Engine, and I want to create a "Generic AI" API so that if I have multiple AI engines in the future, everyone will interact with this "Generic API" instead of individual API.

Moving forward, user will interact with this "Generic AI" API through these 2 ways:

1. User (using Jupyter Notebook - python) => "Generic AI" wrapper => "Generic AI" API => AI Engine API 1 / AI Engine API 2, etc
2. Another program (any programming language) => "Generic AI" API => AI Engine API 1 / AI Engine API 2, etc

I have a question on how to best design the "Generic AI" wrapper and "Generic AI" API.  I want to keep or reuse the original python wrapper as to provide backward compatibility.

- Should I use "Python Wrapper" inside "Generic AI" API?
- Should the "Generic API" have the same specification as "AI Engine" API and "Generic API" just forward it to "AI Engine" API (maybe add the authentication)?

Comment: 1. Probably not, is there a reason you'd want to?  2. No, the generic API can only expose features that are supported by all API engines;  locking to the spec of one particular API would run counter to this.

Comment: Are you planning a generic AI api so that you can keep augmenting different AI capabilities to the system while maintaining the same base url?

Comment: @JohnWu : If I don't use the python wrapper, then I will need to rewrite the same code again inside the Generic AI API, so if the python wrapper is updated, I need to do the same.

Comment: @NachiappanKumarappan : Yes, because in the future I might have more AI engines, so this Generic API is to act as a bridge to multiple AI engines

Comment: I do not understand why you would need to rewrite the same code again. Can't the generic API talk to the AI engine without the wrapper?

Comment: @JohnWu it would mean I copy the wrapper code into the generic API